# Change value of variable inside nested function

Tags: javascript, function

I have variable (csvContent) that I create in StartALL() function, inside that function I call another function called XOR1(). Inside XOR1() function I modify variable csvContent, but first function (StartALL()) doesn't see any changes, how do I make function XOR1() change value for csvContent ?

```
function StartALL() {
    input_1 = parseInt(input_1.value);
    input_2 = parseInt(input_2.value);

    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

    csvContent += "ASD" + "\r\n";
    console.log(csvContent)
    XOR1(input_1, input_2, csvContent);
    console.log(csvContent)

}

function XOR1(input_1, input_2, csvContent) {
    let MOVE1 =  (~input_1 & input_2) | (input_1 & ~input_2);
    csvContent += MOVE1 + "\r\n";
    return csvContent;
 }
```

Comment: You have to assign the returned value to the variable in the calling context. JavaScript is a pass-by-value language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function StartALL() {
    input_1 = parseInt(input_1.value);
    input_2 = parseInt(input_2.value);
        
   let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";

    csvContent += "ASD" + "\r\n";
    console.log(csvContent)
    csvContent = XOR1(input_1, input_2);
    
    console.log(csvContent);

}

function XOR1(input_1, input_2, csvContent) {
    let MOVE1 =  (~input_1 & input_2) | (input_1 & ~input_2);
    csvContent += MOVE1 + "\r\n";
    return csvContent;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

simple

you can't

there is no way you can change the variable in nested functions